# continue the loop if the element does not exist in other arrays in a 3d array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 3d array x [k][n][m] with shape (10, 10, 100) and i need to verify if element m in range(0, 100) does not exist in other arrays x[k-1][n-1] then it can access the loop otherwise it needs to pass to m+1

This is what I did

```
def main(self):
    self.xam = [[[0 for m in range(0, self.Vt)] for n in range(0, self.N)] for x in range(0, self.rn)]
    for k in range(0, self.rn):
        for n in range(0, self.N):
            for m in range(0, self.Vt):
                self.iteration = 0
                if (self.xam[k-1][n-1][m] != 1):
                    while self.iteration < self.Iter_max:
                          if self.NU[k][n][m] == self.AU[k][n][m] == 1:
                             self.xam[k][n][m] = 1
                             print("station", k, "channel", n, "user", m, self.xam[k][n][m])

                          self.iteration += 1
```

the problem that i had is that it does not take the condition into account:

```
  station 7 channel 9 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]


  station 8 channel 0 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: wrong indentation? I guess `self.iteration += 1` should be two indentation level below (move to right).

Comment: @norok2 that was just a mistake when i wrote it here it is not the problem

Comment: I would suggest you create a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including clear input, current output and expected output. Perhaps, I would consider using a smaller size of the inputs. If you do that, your odds of getting a response that way would be vastly superior.